# How to debug js in browserify

Tags: browserify

I have using browserify for new project. It works really well so far.

I have one big issue though. How can I debug each js file separately. It bundles all the files together and points to bundle if error occurs.

I am using chrome and source maps but it doesn't really help in debugging.

Any ideas?

**Update: More info:**

I'm using this command in package.json

```
"start": "watchify scripts/main.js -o scripts/bundle.js --debug",
```

[image]

and getting errors as shown above which is not ideal.

I believe my source maps are on?

[image]

Comment: How is `line 9 of description.js` unhelpful? Are you linting files before building them to catch errors there as well? When/where are you using reactify?

Comment: That error is a standard js syntax error. Typically an incorrect syntax or extra something.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews I get what the error is but my problem is bundle.js. It should tell me where exactly(which file) this error is?

Comment: Do you not have a `views/description.js` file?

Comment: No. The error is still in the bundle.js file and the browser doesn't know anything about the rest of your files., This is telling you which file to look in for the error. Its working as expected.

Comment: Is this the same error you get when you don't use `--debug`?

Comment: No --debug is not making any difference. I get same error with or without --debug.

Comment: Updated my answer below - fix the parse errors, and it should be working again for you from that point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how you are using the command line tool for browserify without any code, but you you should be able to utilize `debug`.

> --debug -d  Enable source maps that allow you to debug your files
>                          separately.

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js --debug
```

For more info on the CLI tool you can look here - https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage

**Edit** After a bit more digging on this - the issue specifically being hit here is a `ParseError` - which means that Browserify is never actually getting to the proper debug stage. Hadn't really thought it through, but this made perfect sense.

In order to test this - I create two simple files:

*a.js*

```
module.exports = function(a) {
    return a;
}
```

*main.js*

```
var a = require('./a.js');
console.log(a("something"));
```

I then ran `browserify` using `watchify` with an `npm` script:

```
"start": "watchify main.js -o bundle.js --debug"
```

Using the script in a browser, and everything worked great - it logged to console as expected.  I then edited `a.js` with a typo:

*a.js*

```
module.exports = function(a) {
    return a---
}
```

The ***browser*** and ***watchify*** threw the error shown above: `path/to/file/a.js:3 ParseError: Unexpected Token`.

Browserify is not able to compile the file properly, so it's throwing an error.  You should be seeing this in the console during the build.

To test that the `--debug` flag works as expected, I modified the code again:

*a.js*

```
module.exports = function(a) {
    return a('something');
}
```

The expectation here would be a `TypeError` since the function now expects `a` to be a function.

The console in the browser now displays:
    `Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function __________ a.js:2`

Fix your parse issues, and `browserify --debug` will once again start behaving as expected.

Comment: In addition, if your source maps aren't working in the browser, then check your browser dev tools settings to make sure source maps are enabled. I know in Chrome I have turned them off before then forgot to turn them back on.